# How do I open Apple Maps from a Google Maps link in Safari?

Tags: safari, safari-extensions, bookmarks, maps, google-maps

I would ideally like a bookmarklet since then I could use it on iOS as well. I tried this Safari extension but I would like an option in the toolbar to open Apple Maps when I'm already on a Google Maps page instead of directly opening Apple Maps form a Google maps link.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're referring to the [ReMap Safari extension](http://www.sidetree.com/extensions.html#ReMap)? Unfortunately, I'm not aware of any existing bookmarklet solution that takes a location highlighted in maps.google.com and opens it in OS X/iOS Maps (nor were my attempts at finding something fruitful).

It's an interesting idea and I'm guessing possibly feasible given that a given location's coordinates are in the maps.google.com URL - if I was up on Javascript, I'd take a crack at it. I'll be interested to see if a solution does pop up!